# Python import library in submodule

Tags: python, import, hdfs, git-submodules

I have the following structure:

```
run.py
app/hdfs_lib_test.py
app/src/HDFSFileReader.py
```

This is a Flask app.

The `HSFDFileReader.py` contains:

```
class HDFSFileReader:
    """This class represents a reader for accessing files in a HDFS."""

    def __init__(self):
        pass

    @classmethod
    def read(cls, file_path):
        lines = []

        try:
            client = Config().get_client('dev')

            with client.read('Serien_de', encoding='utf-8', delimiter='\n') as reader:
                for line in reader:
                    lines.append(line)
        except:
            print("ERROR: Could not read from HDFS.")
            raise

        return lines
```

When I run `./run.py` I get the `ImportError: No module named 'hdfs'`. However the library is installed and I can call `python hdfs_lib_test.py`, which contains the following:

```
from hdfs import Config

try:
    client = Config().get_client('dev')


    with client.read('Serien_de',encoding='utf-8',delimiter='\n') as reader:
        for line in reader:
            print(line)
except:
    raise
```

So to me it seems, that because HDFSFileReader is part of a submodule and `hdfs_lib_test.py` isn't. The former doesn't work, but the later does. But how do I fix the import problem?

I can't be a circular import issue, I searched the whole project for imports of `hdfs` and the `hdfs_lib_test.py` is not used by the actual project.

Comment: Are you sure you're using the same Python interpreter for both invocations?

Comment: Is the import error raised from `hdfs_lib_test.py`? If so: Try logging/printing `sys.path` before the import and check if it's the same for both invocations. There are two more differences: The current directory for both invocations and possibly the Python interpreter used.  Do you run flask in a virtualenv? If so, `run.py` might be using the a different interpreter than what you get by executing `python` directly.

Comment: @jonrsharpe That's the solution, the interpreter was another. Thanks! Could you post this as an answer so I can accept it?